# How do I utilize dot notation when rendering components?

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs, es6-modules

I have a simple component which is supposed to render different kind of fields into my form component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Field extends React.Component {

  render() {
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case 'textarea': {
        return (
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <textarea
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            >
            </textarea>
          </div>
          )
      }
      case 'text': {
        return (
          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm using this component in my form component like this:

```
export default class SubmitForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        .
        .
        .
        <Field
          type="text"
          placeholder="something"
          name="something"
        />
        <Field
          type="textarea"
          placeholder="another"
          name="othername"
        />
        .
        .
        .
    )
  }
}
```

What I have in mind is to somehow implement my field component to be able to use dot notation as explained in [Using Dot Notation for JSX components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type) which I have seen many other libraries and I want to be able to use this component like this:

```
<Field.Text name="sth" placeholder="sth" />
<Field.TextArea name="other" placeholder="other stuff" />
```

But I can't do it the way mentioned in React docs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just create individual components and export them under names:

```
//Field.js
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  ...
}

class Text extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export { Text, TextArea };
```

Then import all the names from the module:

```
import * as Field from './path/to/Field.js';
```

Or if you prefer exporting a default object like so (which is exactly what the example from the documentation is doing, just in a different way):

```
export default { Text, TextArea };
```

Which will use [object shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) and export a default member -- an object literal. Then you can import it like so:

```
import Field from './path/to/Field.js';
```

And finally:

```
<Field.TextArea ... />
```

Or, to get rid of dot notation (you can't do this with the default export option!):

```
import { Text, TextArea } from './path/to/Field.js';

<Text ... />
<TextArea ... />
```

Of course, going exactly by the React documentation, you could do, with class expressions:

```
const Field = {
  Text: class Text extends React.Component { //you can omit the class name here
    //can be stateless functional component if you don't need state
  },
  TextArea: class TextArea extends React.Component {

  }
}

export default Field;
```

Then importing as a default member and using dot notation.

Comment: so actually there is no point in achieving this dot notation I guess. and i should create separate components anyway. and find a way to share mutual event handlers and other stuff between these components. Is this the only way? I mean I've seen other libraries like react-redux-form which provides something like <Control.select> or <Control.textarea>. are they also doing so with just exporting under name of Control?

Comment: @Taxellool Well, it's mostly for organizational purposes. They just have a namespace such as `Field` to group all their field type components together, and exporting the namespace.

Comment: thanks. the final section of your answer actually made me understand the way explained in docs. Anyway right now I don't see a reason to pursue this anymore. the whole purpose of "dot notation" seems to be for organizing as u said. And separate components must be defined either way. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply following the docs.

```
const Field = {
  Text: function Text(props) {
    return <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            />
          </div>;
  },
  Textarea: function Textarea(props) {
    return <div className="col-xs-12">
            <textarea
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            >
            </textarea>
          </div>;
  }
}
```

Then when your dot usage

```
<Field.Text placeholder="something" name="something" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Field extends React.Component {

  render() {
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case 'textarea': {
        return (
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <textarea
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            >
            </textarea>
          </div>
          )
      }
      case 'text': {
        return (
          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name={this.props.name}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

chnage this as following way

```
const Field = {
    text: function(){
      // your text code
    }
}

export default Field;
```

Same way they have mentioned in the facebook react docs. Instead of component you can return object which contain your functions.

Answer (score 0):

my working typescript codes to lazy import dot notation module. for example Nav, Nav.Item, Nav.Menu` from library [react suite](https://rsuitejs.com/components/navbar/)

Original import without react lazy from [react suite docs](https://rsuitejs.com/components/navbar/)

```
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'rsuite';

<Nav>
  <Nav.Item icon={<HomeIcon />} href="/page">
    Home
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item href="/page/google/login">Login</Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Menu title="Tools">
    <Nav.Item onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/bot-detect">
      Selenium Checker
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/moment-timezone">
      Moment Timezone Playground
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/cookies">
      Cookie Manager
    </Nav.Item>
  </Nav.Menu>
</Nav>
```

Convert using React Lazy import

```
const Nav = React.lazy(() => import('rsuite/esm/Nav'));
const NavItem = React.lazy(
  () => import('rsuite/esm/Nav').then(module => ({
    default: module.default.Item,
  })),
);
const NavMenu = React.lazy(
  () => import('rsuite/esm/Nav').then(module => ({
    default: module.default.Menu,
  })),
);
```

usage

```
<Nav>
  <NavItem icon={<HomeIcon />} href="/page">
    Home
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem href="/page/google/login">Login</NavItem>
  <NavMenu title="Tools">
    <NavItem onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/bot-detect">
      Selenium Checker
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/moment-timezone">
      Moment Timezone Playground
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem onClick={navItemClick} href="/page/cookies">
      Cookie Manager
    </NavItem>
  </NavMenu>
</Nav>
```

[image: result]

I also write full code on [my blog](https://www.webmanajemen.com/2023/09/how-to-react-lazy-load-module-with-dot-notation.html)