# Using dot notation with functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Official ReactJs documentation recommends to create components following the [dot notation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type) like the [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) library:

```html
<Card>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

It is very easy to create this structure with the help of a class component:

```js
const CardBody = ({ children }) => <div className='body'>{children}</div>;

class Card extends Component {
  static Body = CardBody;

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='card'>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it's also [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/when-to-use-es6-class-based-react-components-vs-functional-es6-react-components) to use as much as possible functional component. Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this using only functional component.

If I follow [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916839/how-do-i-utilize-dot-notation-when-rendering-components), I'm no more able to use `Card` as a component because he is now an object of components:

```js
const Card = {
  Component: CardComponent,
  Body: CardBody
}

export default Card
```

I'd have to use it that way, and it's not really what I want:

```js
<Card.Component>
  <Card.Body>
  ...
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: people tend to forget that the `class` in JS is just syntax sugar for a normal function.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In function component you can do like so:

```
// Card.react.js
const Card = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
const Body = () => <>Body</>;

Card.Body = Body;
export default Card;

// Usage
import Card from "./Card.react.js";

const App = () => (
  <Card>
    <Card.Body />
  </Card>
);
```

---

Or, you can exploit named exports:

```
// Card.react.js
export const Wrapper = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
export const Body = () => <>Body</>;

// Usage
import * as Card from "./Card.react.js";

const App = () => (
  <Card.Wrapper>
    <Card.Body />
  </Card.Wrapper>
);
```

Comment: Seems to work well with javascript. But I'm using typescript and this one give me a nice error: `Property 'Body' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'` where `FunctionComponent` is the type of `Card` declared like this `const Card: React.FunctionComponent = ...`

Comment: @johannchopin Thats a different question that you should ask

Comment: Yeah that's true I did't mention typescript in the question so I will ask a new one ;)

Comment: For the curious that saw this question and have trouble typing this code in TypeScript you can have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883388/using-dot-notation-with-functional-component-in-typescript

Comment: Is it smart to use dot notation with annonymous functional components?

Answer (score 20):

## For functional components

```
const CardBody = ({ children }) => <div className='body'>{children}</div>;

const Card = (props) => (
  <div className='card'>{props.children}</div>
);
Card.Body = CardBody
```

And then use it like

```
<Card>
  <Card.Body>
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's was just a question of timing for the validation but I upvoted your answer for your time :)

Answer (score 7):

## Using Functional Components and TypeScript

```js
// Card.tsx
const CardRoot = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
const CardBody = () => <>Body</>;

export const Card = CardRoot as typeof CardRoot & {
  Body: typeof CardBody;
};
Card.Body = CardBody;
```

And use like this:

```js
import { Card } from "./Card";

const App = () => (
  <Card>
    <Card.Body />
  </Card>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Function component with Table example

```js
// Table.js
import React from 'react'

const Table = (props) => <div className='table'>{props.children}</div>
const Row = ({ children }) => <div className='tr'>{children}</div>
const Cell = ({ children }) => <div className='td'>{children}</div>

Table.Row = Row
Table.Cell = Cell

export default Table
```

```js
// Something.js
import Table from 'Table.js'

const Something = () => {
  return(<>
    <Table>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>Td 1</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell>Td 2</Table.Cell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table>
  </>)
}

export default Something
```