# Export default and multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I need the following component stucture:

```
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
<Layout>
   <Layout.Header>...</Layout.Header>
   <Layout.Body>...</Layout.Body>
   <Layout.Footer>...</Layout.Footer>
</Layout>
```

I tried to achieve this as follows:

```
import React from "react";

const Layout = (props) => {
  return <div className="layout">{props.children}</div>;
};

const Header = (props) => {
  return <header className="layout__header">{props.children}</header>;
};

const Body = (props) => {
  return <div className="layout__body">{props.children}</div>;
};

const Footer = (props) => {
  return <footer className="layout__footer">{props.children}</footer>;
};

export { Header, Body, Footer };
export default Layout;
```

But this does not seem to work. Can anybody tell me how to export these functions right so that I can use the above structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this answer [Using dot notation with functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882627/using-dot-notation-with-functional-component) I found the solution is:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  return <div className="layout layout--green">{props.children}</div>;
};

const Header = (props) => {
  return <header className="layout__header">{props.children}</header>;
};

const Body = (props) => {
  return <div className="layout__body">{props.children}</div>;
};

const Footer = (props) => {
  return <footer className="layout__footer">{props.children}</footer>;
};

Layout.Header = Header;
Layout.Body = Body;
Layout.Footer = Footer;

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you exported the components, looks good but you shouldn't import the modules like this:

```
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
<Layout>
   <Layout.Header>...</Layout.Header>
   <Layout.Body>...</Layout.Body>
   <Layout.Footer>...</Layout.Footer>
</Layout>
```

you shoud import it like below:

```
import Layout, { Body, Footer, Header } from "./components/Layout";
<Layout>
  <Header />
  <Body />
  <Footer />
</Layout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I could not use them with the dot notation.