# What is this React component composition pattern known as?

Tags: reactjs

```
<Modal>
  <Modal.Header title="Title"/>
  <Modal.Body>
    <div>The body</div>
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

What is this type of React component composition model called and how would you set up the file structure / export statements of Modal, Modal.Header, Modal.Body.

There's a default export that enables this pattern. Something like:

```
// index.tsx
export default {Modal, Header, Body}
```

Comment: They're just properties. Examples of how you do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60882627/3001761

Answer (score -1):

The pattern you're referring to is known as the **Compound Component Pattern**. This pattern allows you to create a parent component (in this case, `Modal`) and define child components (`Modal.Header`, `Modal.Body`, etc.) that can be used within the parent. It's a way to share implicit state and behavior among components.

Here's how you might structure your files and exports:

```
// Modal.tsx
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({ children }) => {
  // Modal implementation
};

export default Modal;
```

```
// ModalHeader.tsx
import React from 'react';

const ModalHeader = ({ title }) => {
  // ModalHeader implementation
};

export default ModalHeader;
```

```
// ModalBody.tsx
import React from 'react';

const ModalBody = ({ children }) => {
  // ModalBody implementation
};

export default ModalBody;
```

And then in your `index.tsx` file, you would import these components and export them as properties of the `Modal` object:

```
// index.tsx
import Modal from './Modal';
import ModalHeader from './ModalHeader';
import ModalBody from './ModalBody';

Modal.Header = ModalHeader;
Modal.Body = ModalBody;

export default Modal;
```

This allows you to use the components in the way you've shown in your example. The `Modal`, `Modal.Header`, and `Modal.Body` components are all accessible from the `Modal` export. This pattern is commonly used in libraries like `react-bootstrap`.

Comment: You can't say from what's shown that those are compound components. The examples [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks) don't actually use subcomponents that are also _properties_ of their parent.