# Creating child element in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

```
<Navbar>
     <Navbar.Item><Navbar.Items>
</Navbar>
```

Here we can easily create a Navbar component. But how to create Navbar child element ***Navbar.Item***  in react.

Comment: Wny you want to use it like Navebar.Item not NavbarItem?

Comment: I think the question is a duplicate. Does this answer your question: [How do I utilize dot notation when rendering components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916839/how-do-i-utilize-dot-notation-when-rendering-components)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pattern known as Compound Components.

You can simply assign another React component as a property of the first.

Example:

```
const NavBar = props => <div>....</div>;

const NavItem = props => <div>....</div>;

NavBar.Item = NavItem;

export default NavBar;
```

Here's a reference blog by Kent Dodds I found when I had first discovered Compound Components: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks